# The iuiautomation event was registered, causing the process to not exit properly

Tags: user-interface

In my dynamic library, I created a thread and registered a structure change event handler by calling IUIAutomation::AddStructureChangedEventHandler for the desktop root node. The thread is always running.
When I do not call the anti-registration function (StopFocusChangedEventListening), clicking to exit the program will affect the program's normal call of TerminateProcess and ExitProcess, and the program's window will be destroyed (WM_DESTROY), but the background cannot exit, and the program will not exit until dozens of seconds later. Forcefully kill the thread and exit;
When I first call the anti-registration function (StopFocusChangedEventListening) and then click to exit, the program exits normally;
Now my problem is that I want to call the anti-registration function (StopFocusChangedEventListening) when the program exits, but this will affect the normal exit of the program. What should I do?

I created the thread in DllMain:
CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)WorkThread, hModule, 0, NULL);
In WorkThread:
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

Monitor the WM_DESTROY message of the main window, first call the anti-registration function (RemoveStructureChangedEventHandler) and then distribute the DESTROY message, but it has no effect(The main window did not receive WM_CLOSE message)

Comment: Hi! You might want to think more carefully about the tags you've used on this question - the site is very busy, and tags are a way for people to find questions they'll be able to help with. Right now, there's no programming language or technology mentioned here at all, so those people won't be able to find it. You can click [edit] and add some more; you might want to add a bit more formatting as well, as the first paragraph is quite hard to read.